# Android SSL Handshake Exception Failure in SSL library Usually a Protocol Error

Tags: android, exception, ssl

I want my app to show data about Gold Prices. I am able to run my app on

emulators(GenyMotion) on Android 5.0,4.4.4 and 4.3 but if run on actual device

I am getting the following error(attached the screenshot) (4.4.4).I am able to

run on an actual device(4.0.3) .I have searched regarding this but I

could not find a solution on this.can anybody help regarding this ?

[SSL Handshake Exception ] : (http://s13.postimg.org/bk7m0fqc7/unnamed.jpg

Comment: Post the used server so that we can see what TLS modes and ciphers it supports. I assume that this may be the problem.

Comment: @robert : I am reading from JSON Page . https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/BUNDESBANK/BBK01_WT5511.json